# React.useMemo in class component

Tags: reactjs, memoization, react-usememo

Is there a way to use this hook or some its analogue of the React API in the case of a class component?

I'm wondering, should I use some third party memo helpers in the case of a class component (eg. **lodash memo**, **memoizeOne**, etc.) or there is exist some official react API way for class components.

Thanks for any help.

P.S.

I want to generate uuid in the case of changed Children.

with SFC component I could use useMemo like this

```
const keyValue = useMemo(() => uuid()(), [children])
```

But how to achieve the same for class-based components without any thirdparty, etc. 
P.P.S. I'm not using Redux, etc. only pure React.js

Comment: See [Selectors](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops):

> If you want to **re-compute some data only when a prop changes**, [use a memoization helper](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization).

The docs use [`memoizeOne`](https://github.com/alexreardon/memoize-one) as library, so this would be a good choice. You can also change `keyValue` as part of a side effect with [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.keyValue = uuid()()
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.children !== prevProps.children) {
    this.keyValue = uuid()()
    // alternative: store keyValue as state to trigger re-render
  }
}
```

`getDerivedStateFromProps` can be an alternative for rare cases, other options [are usually preferred](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

#### Why `useMemo` is not a good choice with `uuid()`

> **You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.** In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo))

A memoized value `const keyValue = useMemo(() => uuid()(), [children])` might be re-calculated despite `children` being the same in React future. This case could lead to inconsistencies, if `uuid()` returns a new id, but `children` haven't changed.

For function components an alternative is `useRef` with `useEffect` depending on your use case.

Comment: Thank you @ford04 for your answer

Comment: I have been searching for it for a while!

Comment: I've found that `memoize` function is much easier to use and closer to `useMemo`, than `componentDidMount` / `componentDidUpdate`. Pay attention to `memoize` techinque described here - https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization

Answer (score 3):

Use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). The official React docs mentions this technique [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#updating-state-based-on-props).

> As of version 16.3, the recommended way to update state in response to props changes is with the new static getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      values: props.values,
      childrenIds: []
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.values !== state.values) {
      return {
        values: props.values,
        childrenIds: generateIds(props.values)
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.state.childrenIds);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @resolritter. Thank you for the answer but I was wondering about memoization, not state changing based on props)

Comment: Notice the `props.values !== state.values`; you're only regenerating the `childrenIds` in case the props changes, so it effectively is memoization (it keeps track of the last input and doesn't recompute unless the input changes).