# How to Run Multiple Filters Peformatically Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Basically I have a React frontend that receives from an API an array with more than 10,000 objects and inside this object it has several properties.

Like this:

```
const myArray =    
      [
         {
              userStatus: 'status1',
              userOrigin: 'city',
              userCountry: 'USA',
              ...
         },
         {
              userStatus: 'status2',
              userOrigin: 'city',
              userCountry: 'USA',
              ...
         },
         {
              userStatus: 'status3',
              userOrigin: 'city',
              userCountry: 'USA',
              ...
         },
        ....
    ]
```

I need to know the length of some properties so what I'm doing is using filter().

```
...
myArray.filter((a) => a.userStatus === 'status1').length
myArray.filter((a) => a.userStatus === 'status2').length
myArray.filter((a) => a.userStatus === 'status3').length
...
```

The problem is that as there is a lot of data and I need to make these filters for several parameters it ends up becoming something extremely non-performing, sometimes even making the browser crash. Is there any way I can do this more efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)?

Comment: never actually used

Answer (score 0):

The [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook can often help with things like this, by reducing unnecessary recalculation of an expensive value.

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
// ...
function MyComponent({myArray}) {
  const countStatus1 = useMemo(()=> myArray.filter(a => a.userStatus === 'status1').length, [myArray]);
  const countStatus2 = useMemo(()=> myArray.filter(a => a.userStatus === 'status2').length, [myArray]);
  const countStatus3 = useMemo(()=> myArray.filter(a => a.userStatus === 'status3').length, [myArray]);
  // ...
}
```

Another thing you can do, in conjunction with the memoization, is to calculate all the counts in a single loop, using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). In the case above this should be 3x more efficient.

```
const counts = myArray.reduce((a, o) => {
  if(!a[o.userStatus]) a[o.userStatus] = 0;
  a[o.userStatus]++;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(counts);
// example output, object of statuses with their counts:
// => { status1: 41, status2: 9, status3: 16 }
```

Comment: Very good! A question. do you know if there is any alternative for me to do this using class component? I'm using an old version of react

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930571/react-usememo-in-class-component#61932846