# Is there an equivalent to UseMemo or UseCallback for React class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization

As the title says, how can I reproduce useMemo or useCallback with React class component? I am doing some heavy calculation and I don't want the component to recalculate the value every time it's rendered again. Is the only solution to convert my class component to a function component?

Comment: try this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930571/react-usememo-in-class-component

Answer (score 3):

`useMemo` - You can store the memoized version directly on the instance, along with any information that you want to use to invalidate and recalculate that information. See [*What about memoization?*](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization) in the React *You Probably Don't Need Derived State* article.

`useCallback` - You typically don't need to create callbacks when using a class component, you make them methods of the class (perhaps `bind`ing them in the constructor) or assign arrow functions to properties in the constructor, so the need for `useCallback` doesn't arise. Those methods can use `this.state`, `this.setState`, and when setting new state based on existing state, the callback form of `this.setState`. `useCallback` is more helpful in function components because typically the callbacks are created within the function, and you don't want to use a new copy on every render.

Here's an example using a very quick-and-dirty memoization helper (you may want a library instead, as described in the article linked above). Notice how `derivedValue` is only updated when `value1` or `value2` change, not when `value3` changes. Also note that the click handler is stable (doesn't change on each render), so we only see `Button` render once.

```js
// VERY BASIC shallow check to see if the dependencies changed
function depsChanged(oldDeps, newDeps) {
    return !oldDeps || oldDeps.length !== newDeps.length || oldDeps.some((dep, index) => dep !== newDeps[index]);
}

// PureComponent nly re-renders when props change, so it's a handy way to check that
// our click handler doesn't change unnecessarily
class Button extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        const { clickHandler, text } = this.props;
        console.log(`Button rendering`);
        return <input type="button" onClick={clickHandler} value={text} />;
    }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
    // A value we derive from props
    derivedValue: 0;

    // The dependencies we used when calculating `value` in `render`
    valueDeps = null;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Handy so `this` is always the component instance when `clickHandler` is called
        this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
    }

    clickHandler() {
        console.log(`derivedValue = ${this.derivedValue}`);
    }

    render() {
        const { value1, value2, value3 } = this.props;

        // Do we need to recreate `derivedValue`?
        const newDeps = [value1, value2]
        if (depsChanged(this.valueDeps, newDeps)) {
            // Yes
            console.log(`Recalculating derivedValue from ${value1} and ${value2}`);
            this.valueDeps = newDeps;
            this.derivedValue = value1 + value2; // Stand-in for the complex operation
        }

        return <div>
            <div>value1 = {value1}</div>
            <div>value2 = {value2}</div>
            <div>value3 = {value3}</div>
            <div>derivedValue = {this.derivedValue}</div>
            <Button clickHandler={this.clickHandler} text="Click Me" />
        </div>;
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        value1: 0,
        value2: 0,
        value3: 0,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Another way to do callbacks. I prefer to use the method syntax above, but
        // people also do this.
        this.incVaue1 = () => this.setState(({value1}) => ({value1: value1 + 1}));
        this.incVaue2 = () => this.setState(({value2}) => ({value2: value2 + 1}));
        this.incVaue3 = () => this.setState(({value3}) => ({value3: value3 + 3}));
    }

    render() {
        const { value1, value2, value3 } = this.state;
        const { incVaue1, incVaue2, incVaue3 } = this;

        return <div>
            <Example value1={value1} value2={value2} value3={value3} />
            <div>
                <input type="button" onClick={incVaue1} value="Increment value1" />
                <input type="button" onClick={incVaue2} value="Increment value2" />
                <input type="button" onClick={incVaue3} value="Increment value3" />
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't come with a built in way to do memoization for class components, but you can use an external memoization library, or create your own if you want. For example, using [memoize-one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoize-one):

```
import memoizeOne from 'memoize-one';

class Example extends React.Component {

  expensiveCalculation = memoizeOne((someValue) => {
    // ...
  });

  render() {
    const result = this.expensiveCalculation(this.props.someProp);

    // ...
  }
}
```

> how can I reproduce [...] useCallback

Callbacks don't usually need to be memoized in class components. If your callback is simply a method on the class, it will automatically be a stable reference between renders.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {

  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.onClick} />
  }
}
```